How do I deploy my site from 3 projects to hosting
I'm writing an e-commerce website which includes 3 projects:

Admin: Next.JS project
Client: Next.JS project
Server: Nest.JS project
DB: Using PostgreSQL in Server via TypeORM

It's my first multiple projects site and first site with server and database so I'm confused about how do I deploy it correctly, which hosting I should choose, how to make them working together, how do I deploy database correctly. There isn't much info in the net or I just googled it wrong
See site links in github:

Admin: github link
Admin: github link
Admin: github link


With your requirement above, please just find hosting provider that support .NET and Postgre. Since this is new project, just make sure to find shared hosting, it will save your budget. FYI, I use Asphostportal to host .net website, however it seems they don't support for Postgre. Unless you can change your database to MySQL or MSSQL, then you can go with this host.
